# CKEditor5 - Making Mention work together with Markdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor5 and trying to make the Mention plugin work together with the Markdown plugin. Currently, adding a @mention works but it is exported simply as @mention by editor.getData(), and instanciating an editor with data = '@mention' will not lead the package to parsing this data as a mention in the editor.

Ideally I'd like to have an escaped markdown inline block such as {objectName[objectId]} as the data input, which would then be upcast to the model as a MentionAttribute. For downcasting, one would need to find these MentionAttributes and downcast them to the correct syntax.

I have no clue how to do this, I am new to CKEditor5 the architecture of the package is complex and it can be hard to add customization. I know that there are upcast and downcast converters I can create, but I couldn't find anything for matching text and inserting it into the model.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work by:

- Using the Editor as a controlled component
- Implementing a custom syntax for mentions in our markdown format
- Passing markdown converted into HTML interpretable by the Model layer, including mention syntax used by the Mention plugin, to the data props of the Editor wrapper
- On onChange events, pass the HTML converted back into markdown to the controller

Comment: Can you please shre a code sample for the same. I am looking for something similar.